# jQuery Checkboxs as radio buttons with ability to uncheck all

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes that act as radio buttons. These need to stay checkboxes rather than radio buttons, to be consistent with other checkboxes in the same form. The question is what to do when a user wants to uncheck all after making a selection. My solution does not allow for this. Clicking on a selected checkbox simply remains checked.
[Edit} Since the phrase "uncheck all" seems to have cause some confusion, let me try to explain better. With the code I have in place now, shown below, if a user selects a checkbox, then selects another checkbox, that user's first selection will unchecked. The problem is that if, now, the user decides to uncheck their (currently checked) second selection, which would then leave all checkboxes unchecked, they cannot do that because you cannot uncheck a box once it is checked, except to check a different box.

```
$(".OverLen").on("click", function()
{
    Current = this.id;
    if($("#"+Current).prop("checked", true))
    {
        $(".OverLen").prop("checked", false);
        $("#"+Current).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

**[Edit]**
The only solution I've found so far is to set a global variable. But it seems like an awkward solution:

**At page load:**

OverLenID = ''; // Used to hold selected OverLen id

Then I changed the function to:

```
  $(".OverLen").on("click", function()
  {
     var Current = this.id;
     if($("#"+Current).is(':checked'))
     {
        if(Current == OverLenID)
        {
           $("#"+Current).prop("checked", false);
           OverLenID = '';
        }
        else
        {
           $(".OverLen").not(this).prop("checked", false);
           OverLenID = Current;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        OverLenID = '';
     }
  });
```

**HTML**
Since it was requested, here is the basics of the HTML.
All checkboxes are contained within a div. Nothing special about the div, except that there are 3 divs contained within that div, each supporting rows of checkboxes. An ordinary checkbox looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ThisCheckboxID" name="Acc[]" value="ThisValue" />
<label for="ThisCheckboxID">CheckboxLabelName</label><br />
```

The checkboxes with a class of "OverLen" look like this:

```
<input class="OverLen" type="checkbox" id="OLA" name="Acc[]" value="OLA" />
<label for="OLA">Label Text A</label>
<div class="ANote">Info Text</div>
<input class="OverLen" type="checkbox" id="OLB" name="Acc[]" value="OLB" />
<label for="OLB">Label text B</label>
<div class="ANote">Info Text')</div>
<input class="OverLen" type="checkbox" id="OLC" name="Acc[]" value="OLC" />
<label for="OLC">Label Text C</label>
<div class="ANote">Info Text</div>
```

Comment: `$(".OverLen").not(this).prop("checked", false);`

Comment: @bassxzero Sorry - I misunderstood. That doesn't solve the problem. Although, thanks, it does eliminate a line of code. Perhaps I should be using onchange ...

Comment: @RationalRabbit post HTML please, you had mentioned that there are other groups of checkboxes. It'd be a  waste of time trying to write code blindly.

Comment: @zer00ne - respectfully, it is irrelevant. Checkboxes are checkboxes. The only relevant factor would be that each has a unique ID, which they do.

Comment: @RationalRabbit then I'll assume that each checkbox is proceeded by a matched label. Each checkbox/label pair is followed by a br. The whole group of checkbox/label pairs are nested within a fieldset which in turn is nested within a form. The uncheck/check all checkbox (and it's label) for that group is nested within the legend. The wording of your question is a little difficult to understand -- mentioning "uncheck all" which means you were referring to the toggling behavior of each checkbox *or* you have (or need) an uncheck/check all master checkbox (the one nested in the legend).. not sure.

Comment: @zer00ne - Thank you for your response. At your request, I have included some HTML But I must reiterate, this is a jQuery question. No, there is no fieldset and there is no "check all" or "uncheck all" checkbox. Of course, that could be easily done, but that is not the intention. I'm sorry if the title was misleading to you. There is only so much space available in a question title..

Comment: @RationalRabbit Ok keep in mind that the difference between a radio and checkbox is behavior and style, other than that, they are just input tags. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250427/2813224) involves radios that look like checkboxes but behave like both flawlessly. Also keep in mind that jQuery is JavaScript and JavaScript is always an acceptable (most agree better) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `type = "radio"` is Your Friend

- Save yourself the trouble and use `<input type="radio">` because they are designed for mutually exclusive selection behavior (ie only one can be checked in a group).
- Ensure that each group share the same `[name]` attribute value. In the demo each group name is `cg` suffixed with it's index number.
- All radios have unique #ids and a `<label for=` **ID of radio** `>...`. Set all radios to `display: none` (or out of the way and hidden) and [style the `<label>s` to appear as checkboxes](http://doodlenerd.com/html-control/css-checkbox-generator).

Just by doing these 3 steps alone you no longer need to implement that behavior in jQuery/JavaScript. Expansion is easy as changing a single letter in the names and ids on additional groups (even easier if dynamically generated).

The last requirement is that each checkbox needs to have a toggling behavior like a checkbox (ie user can check/uncheck directly by clicking). This is accomplished by simple Vanilla JavaScript. For future expansion, stable, simple, and maintainable code wrap everything in a `<form>` tag and use [**HTMLFormElement API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). Further details are commented in the demo.

```js
// Register the click event to the <form>
var form = document.forms[0].onclick = fauxChx;

// Pass the Event Object (e)
function fauxChx(e) {
  /*
  Reference the clicked element's adjacent tag before it
  e.target is the clicked tag and .pES is the radio
  */
  const node = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  // if clicked tag is a label...
  if (e.target.matches('label')) {
    // and if the radio is checked...
    if (node.checked) {
      // uncheck it...
      node.checked = false;
    } else {
      // otherwise check it
      node.checked = true;
    }
  }
  /*
  By closing function the event no longer bubbles to 
  trigger anything else and by focusing on the label
  and excluding all other tags, we have isolated the
  event and as a result there are no conflicts. This
  programming pattern is called Event Delegation.
  */
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 700 16px/1.25 Verdana;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

fieldset {
  width: fit-content;
}

.chx {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px groove #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.chx:checked+label::before {
  content: '✔';
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}

label::after {
  content: attr(for);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>fauxChx<br>Group 0</legend>
    <input id='cx0' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx0'></label><br>
    <input id='cx1' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx1'></label><br>
    <input id='cx2' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx2'></label><br>
    <input id='cx3' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx3'></label><br>
    <input id='cx4' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx4'></label><br>
    <input id='cx5' name='cg0' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cx5'></label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>fauxChx<br>Gruop 1</legend>
    <input id='cy0' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy0'></label><br>
    <input id='cy1' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy1'></label><br>
    <input id='cy2' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy2'></label><br>
    <input id='cy3' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy3'></label><br>
    <input id='cy4' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy4'></label><br>
    <input id='cy5' name='cg1' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cy5'></label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>fauxChx<br>Gruop 2</legend>
    <input id='cz0' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz0'></label><br>
    <input id='cz1' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz1'></label><br>
    <input id='cz2' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz2'></label><br>
    <input id='cz3' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz3'></label><br>
    <input id='cz4' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz4'></label><br>
    <input id='cz5' name='cg2' class='chx' type='radio'>
    <label for='cz5'></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent solution. I'm sure it will come in handy in the future. Also like the links you provided. That said, I believe I'll stick with my second solution using a global variable (which, after some thought, I edited in my question). These are only 5 "either/or" checkboxes out of a list of 30, and I really don't want to change how they are handled on the back end by giving them a different name. As it is, they are just another checkbox with a different class.

Comment: You are very welcome. When you gain more experience you'll gravitate towards JavaScript and use less jQuery. jQuery is convenient and versatile but on the other hand there's a lot going on under the surface and it will get in the way. I believe that's what you are experiencing now with this problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line to uncheck all of the other checkboxes of the same class.

`$(".OverLen").not(this).prop("checked", false);`

So your function would look something like this.

```
$(".OverLen").on("change", function()
{
   var $this = $(this); // cache this; very minor speed opt. 

    if( $this.prop("checked", true) )
    {
        $(".OverLen").not(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, as I said, this is more concise, but doesn't solve the problem. Still, if a checkbox is checked, you cannot uncheck it, other than making another selection. The only way I can think of is to set a global on page load, which would only be changed when a box is checked. Thus, you would always know what checkbox has been checked and clear it if checked again.

Comment: I edited my question to show the use of a global variable. This works, but it seems there must be a way to do this within the jQuery function without the global.

Comment: I apologize. I don't know what I was missing in this solution. This actually works just fine. I think I must not have realized this was the whole solution in itself, and had other code that was getting in the way. Thanks @bassxzero.